# Laravel Policies registration return false on Voyager

Tags: laravel, voyager

I added Voyager to my project, which uses a policy to check if a user can view/edit a specific project.

When I try to open the Projects table from Voyager, I get a 403 error.

It seems that when I remove the policy from my "policies" array in AuthServiceProvider, I am able to access the projects table in Voyager just fine.

I tried adding in my policy a check on $user->role_id == 1 (check if user is admin), but still no success, even if I replace the response of the policy to true.

Any idea what the issue might be? Thanks

Edit:

Desired behavior: I want to restrict the user from editing/viewing projects that are not his, however I want the admin to be able to access all projects from Voyager.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up fixing it by adding the policy that I am using on the Projects bread, and had to add browse, add, edit, delete and read methods returning true.

It seems that once you have a policy registered Voyager will pick it up so you need to tell it how it should behave.

```
<?php

namespace App\Policies;

use App\User;
use App\Project;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;

class ProjectPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    /**
     * Create a new policy instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    public function browse(){
        return true;
    }
    
    public function add(){
        return true;
    }

    public function delete(){
        return true;
    }

    public function edit(){
        return true;
    }

    public function read(){
        return true;
    }


    public function access(User $user, Project $project){
        return $project->owner_id == $user->id ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried some basics steps like :
`php artisan route:clear`
`composer dump-autoload`